# Динамическая смена CSS и запись в куки

Tags: css

Со сменой CSS я разобрался:

```
<link id="CSSsource" href="оригинал CSS" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<input type="button" value="изменить стиль на тёмный" onclick="document.getElementById('CSSsource').href='добавочный CSS'" />
```

Но в куки это не записывается, поэтому после перезагрузки страницы всё возвращается к исходному CSS. 
Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как реализовать это и куда именно вписать в мой вышеуказанный код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css.php

```
<?
$id = 1; // default
if (!empty($_COOKIE['CSSID'])) $id = $_COOKIE['CSSID'];
if (!empty($_GET['CSSID'])) $id = $_GET['CSSID'];
setcookie ('CSSID' , $id, time()+3600 * 24 * 365);
header('Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8');
if (file_exists('style'.$id.'.css')) {
  require 'style'.$id.'.css';
  } else require 'style1.css';
?>
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function chCSS(id) {
    document.getElementById('CSSsource').href='/style/css.php?CSSID='+id;
    }
</script>
<link id="CSSsource" href="/style/css.php" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<input type="button" value="изменить стиль на тёмный" onclick="chCSS(1)" />
```

Соответственно стили храним в файлах style1.css, style2.css и т.д., они сохраняются в сессию (т.е. в этом браузере они будут храниться до закрытия) Пути, естественно, правим на свои.

Comment: Лучше с куками. На дольше хватит выбора определенного стиля. Сессия 10-15 минут, а куку можно и на год, чтобы человеку каждый день не выбирать заново.

Comment: Я с куками и хочу сделать.
Т.е., как я понял, первый вариант - сессия, а второй - куки?

Comment: Переписал для куков. И Никита, это 1 вариант) Просто он в 2 файлах и расширять его проще.

Comment: Спасибо большое.
В ближайшее время посмотрю, проверю работу.
Просто работаю над дизайном блога на tut.blog.by Там ничего кроме CSS редактировать нельзя. Благо есть плагин, с помощью которого можно вставить HTML, PHP и javascript... Но от этого не особо легко.

Answer (score 3):

Тогда уж `onclick="имя-функции-яваскрипт"` и делаете функцию в которой будет

```
document.getElementById('CSSsource').href='добавочный CSS';
```

и запись в куки (вот [статья](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/js/Cookies.php)). Сами параметры себе выберите по времени и так далее. Потом только при формировании страницы из (например) PHP проверяйте, есть в куках css или нет, чтобы не менять после загрузки яваскриптом. А то получится загрузится одно и будет на глазах меняться, это очень некрасиво. Для времени хранения, чтобы не мучались, ставите

```
 expires = new Date(); // получаем текущую дату
 expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1000 * 86400 * 365)); // это на год
```

Comment: Спасибо. Посмотрю.